# ExtJS Tree panel not show elements correctly

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs5

I'm creating a tree panel with data from a JSON file, when I expand a categorie shows elements correctly but if i expand another categorie the elements opened desappier, this happens with all elements in the expand and contract event.

Here are a pictures of the behaviour

Fist expand event:

[image]

Second expand event:

[image]

Third expand event:

[image]

Here is the code that i'm using:

The model:

```
Ext.define('app.model.modeloCapa', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: ['nombre','url'],

proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: "data/jsonprovisional.json",  
    reader: {
        type    : 'json',
        root    : 'Result',
    }
}});
```

The store:

```
Ext.define('app.store.capa', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
requires: 'app.model.modeloCapa',
model: 'app.model.modeloCapa'});
```

The view:

```
initComponent: function() {

    var anchoPanatallaRes = window.screen.width;
    var altoPantallaRes = window.screen.height;

    var anchoTOC = 330;
    var altoTOC = 473;

    if (anchoPanatallaRes <= 1024) {
        anchoTOC = 282;
        altoTOC = 373;
    }
    var treeStore = Ext.getStore('capa');

    function addUrl(value, p, record) {
        return value ? Ext.String.format(
                '<a href="'+value+'"target="_blank"'+'>Ver metadato'+'</a>'
        ):'';
    }

    var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        title: '',      
        reserveScrollbar: true,
        loadMask: true,
        useArrows: true,
        rootVisible: false,
        store: 'capa',
        allowDeselect : true,
        border : true,
        animate: true,
        listeners: {
            checkchange: function(node, checked, eOpts) {
                console.log('nodo seleccionado:', node, checked, eOpts);
            },
            select: function( record, index, eOpts ){
                console.log('Elemento seleccionado:', record, index, eOpts);
            },
            beforedeselect: function( record, index, eOpts ){
                console.log("Elemento deseleccionado :", record);
            }
        },
        columns: [{
            xtype: 'treecolumn',
            text: 'Capa',
            flex: 5,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'nombre'
        },{
            text: 'Metadato',
            flex: 2,
            dataIndex: 'url',
            renderer: addUrl
        }],

        tbar: [{
            labelWidth: 100,
            xtype: 'triggerfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Nombre capa:',
            triggerCls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',
            onTriggerClick: function() {
                this.reset();
                treeStore.clearFilter();
                this.focus();
            },
            enableKeyEvents: true,
            listeners: {
                keyup: function() {
                    var field = tree.down('textfield'),
                    v;

                    try {
                        v = new RegExp(field.getValue(), 'i');
                        treeStore.filter({
                            filterFn: function(node) {
                                var children = node.childNodes,
                                len = children && children.length,

                                //Visibilidad de los hijos 
                                visible = node.isLeaf() ? v.test(node.get('nombre')) : false,   i;

                                //Visibilidad de los padres
                                for (i = 0; i < len && !(visible = children[i].get('visible')); i++);

                                return visible;
                            },
                            id: 'campoFiltroCapa'
                        });
                    } catch (e) {
                        field.markInvalid('Expresión no valida');
                    }
                },
                buffer: 250
            }
        }, {
            xtype : 'button',
            text: 'Click',
            id : 'btnApagarCapas',
            action: 'apagarCapas',
            tooltip : 'Apagar todas las capas',
            padding:0,
            listeners : {
                click : function(boton) {
                    console.log("BOTON PRESIONADO!!");
                }
            }
        }]
    });

    Ext.apply(this, {
        title: 'TABLA CONTENIDO',
        id: 'ventanaCapas',
        constrain: true,
        header : {
            titlePosition : 2,
            titleAlign : 'center'
        },
        closable : false,
        width : anchoTOC,
        height : altoTOC,
        x : 20,
        y : 270,
        layout : 'fit',
        animCollapse : true,
        collapsible : true,
        collapseDirection : Ext.Component.DIRECTION_LEFT,
        listeners : {
            collapse : function(p) {
            }
        },
        items: [tree],
    });
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

And teh JSON file that i'm using:

```
{"Result": [{
"nombre": "Componente Biótico y Abiótico",
"id": 1,
    "Result":[{
        "nombre": "Recursos hídricos",
        "id": 2,
            "Result": [{
                "id": 268,
                "titulo": "HIDROGEOLOGIA_ATLAS",
                "url": "http://srsigaremap:8080/geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage",
                "nombre": "HIDROGEOLOGIA_ATLAS",
                "metadato": "",
                "wfs": false,
                "leaf": true,
                "checked": false
            }]
    },{
        "nombre": "Fauna",
        "id": 3,
            "Result": [{
                "id": 269,
                "titulo": "AVES_ATLAS_ATLAS",
                "url": "http://srsigaremap:8080/geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage",
                "nombre": "AVES_ATLAS_ATLAS",
                "metadato": "",
                "wfs": false,
                "leaf": true,
                "checked": false
            }]
    },{
        "nombre": "Ecosistemas",
        "id": 4,
            "Result": [{
                "id": 270,
                "titulo": "ECOSISTEMAS_MARINOS_ATLAS",
                "url": "http://srsigaremap:8080/geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage",
                "nombre": "ECOSISTEMAS_MARINOS_ATLAS",
                "metadato": "",
                "wfs": false,
                "leaf": true,
                "checked": false
            }]
    }]},{
"nombre": "ARE",
"id": 5,
"Result":[{
        "nombre": "Minero Energético",
        "id": 2,
            "Result": [{
                "id": 271,
                "titulo": "GASODUCTO_ATLAS",
                "url": "http://srsigaremap:8080/geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage",
                "nombre": "GASODUCTO_ATLAS",
                "metadato": "",
                "wfs": false,
                "leaf": true,
                "checked": false
            },{
                "id": 272,
                "titulo": "TITULOS_MINEROS_ATLAS",
                "url": "http://srsigaremap:8080/geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage",
                "nombre": "TITULOS_MINEROS_ATLAS",
                "metadato": "",
                "wfs": false,
                "leaf": true,
                "checked": false
            }]
    }]},{
"nombre":"Agrología",
"id":13,
"Result":[{
        "nombre": "Cobertura y uso",
        "id": 2,
            "Result": [{
                "id": 271,
                "titulo": "COBERTURA_VEGETAL_GUAJIRA_ATLAS",
                "url": "http://srsigaremap:8080/geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage",
                "nombre": "COBERTURA_VEGETAL_GUAJIRA_ATLAS",
                "metadato": "",
                "wfs": false,
                "leaf": true,
                "checked": false
            }]
    }]}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TreePanel works fine only if all your nodes have a unique 'id' property.

In your JSON file, we can see that "Recursos hídricos" node, "Minero Energético" and "Cobertura y uso" have the same id :

```
"nombre": "Recursos hídricos",
"id": 2

"nombre": "Minero Energético",
"id": 2

"nombre": "Cobertura y uso",
"id": 2
```

That's why "Recursos hídricos" disapear when you click on your "ARE" node. Make sure to set a unique ID to all your nodes (no matter the level they are) and your problem will be solved.